# Delete all folder not containing filename matching glob/regex

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell-scripting, find

I want to do the following. I have depth 2 file hierarchy like this:

```
A
| B
| | g
| | h50000
| C
```

Where A, B, C are folders. I want to delete all folders without files matching specific patters, (in my case *50000* is pattern, glob style) on depth level 2. (In this example folder C should only be deleted, alongside its content, while A remains)

In my application I'm fine if I delete all folders where neither children contains filename matching a pattern. (It would make it easier to not delete A without specifying on which depth I'm deleting).

How would I be able to do it in bash on Linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `find` you could exclude a pattern:

```
find \! -name '*50000*' -delete
```

Escaping `!` is necessary due to its usage in shells.

Directories with contents will not be deleted.

WARNING: since from your question it is a bit unclear to me - this WILL delete other files in folders that have a `50000` pattern, e.g. `A/B/g` will be removed and only files (and dirs) with name `50000` (including their parent direcories) be kept!

---

For deleting all directories that have no `50000` file in them and keep directories with such files along with the other contents of this directory, I'd suggest a two-step method:

1. list all files and directories and safe into text file

   ```
   find . -depth -mindepth 1 > all
   ```
2. list directories that need to be kept (find file and print dir only)

   ```
   find . -depth -name '*50000*' printf '%h\n' > keep
   ```
3. pick the deletable files and directories with an inverted `grep`

   ```
   grep -vf keep all > deletable
   ```
4. use this list for deletion (just a sample)

   ```
   while read line 
   do

      find . -wholename "$line" -delete

   done < deletable
   ```

Note that point 4 is slow due to the nature of being a line-per-line shell script. Not the nicest, but will do the job.

---

Alternatively (and simpler): If you have root access intermedially change the `i`-attribute, preventing changes, including deletion, delete everything (as deletion is not allowed for `i`-flagged files and dirs), and remove the `i` flag in the end.

```
#%h goes for parent directories of our hits
find -name '*5000*' -printf '%h\0' | xargs -0 chattr -R +i '{}'
#be careful now ....
rm -r *
chattr -i -R *
```